# SQL: Is this normalized? Extra field in an entity

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, database-normalization, erd

I'm working on an ERD for a context where a therapist can make tests for clients to take, and there is a rule that after creating the test, the therapist can add items to it until the test has been taken by a user.

There is a:

### TestSession entity

```
SessionID, 
TestID PK, 
etc etc
```

and a

### Test entity

```
TestID
Taken t/f
```

There would a trigger that sets `Test.Taken` to true if a Session with the matching TestID is added. A group member made a case that `Test.Taken` is repetitive and not normalized, since the same information can be approximated by searching `TestSession` for the particular TestID as needed. In this case, normalization being 4NF or BCNF.

Does it more make sense to have a `Test.Taken` field that's updated by a trigger or to find the same info ad hoc from `TestSession` when it's needed?

Comment: Simply add the Test records as the test is taken, and perform `TestSession LEFT JOIN Test` with a null test cast to true/false to identify taken/not-taken tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try an answer from a practical point of view. Although normalization is important, I would design more starting from how your data is really used. Also, I will provide examples based on T-SQL, but they can easily be converted to any SQL flavor.

**1) not defining Test.Taken**. To get entity information along with its usage you should write a query like the following:

```
SELECT T.TestID, CAST((WHEN TS.TestID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS Taken
FROM Test T
    LEFT JOIN TestSession TS ON TS.TestID = T.TestID
```

This can be embodied into a view if it is used in several places.

To insert data in your structure, you simply make an `INSERT` into `TestSession` table.

**2) defining Test.Taken**. To get the same information as above, the query becomes simpler and faster:

```
SELECT T.TestID, T.Taken
FROM Test T
```

However, a session insertion will be slightly complex (trigger is not required, just use a transaction):

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET XACT_ABORT ON

INSERT INTO TestSession (TestID)
VALUES (@TestID)

UPDATE Test SET Taken = 1 WHERE TestID = @TestID
COMMIT
```

If you do not handle a very large number of records (~10-100M or more), first approach can be used as it simplifies data persistence and reduces the risk of inconsistencies. For very larger structures where performance becomes a problem, redundancies may help.